# Let visitor upload file to expresso store order

Tags: expresso-store

Is there anyway to enable a file upload(s) to the expresso store order during any step of the checkout process?

Comment: I would prefer doing this somehow using the custom order fields..?

Answer (score 0):

File uploads is not possible with stores module. It is created for take orders and payments. If you want to do so it can easily done by custom code.

Are you good in front end custom code with ajax and php it will take no time to do so.